# How to hide layered navigation filter if all products in category have the same value?

Tags: layered-navigation, filter

Imagine having a category with 10 products, all having the same weight of 2 lbs.

Weight filter will still show in layered navigation as:

**Weight**

2 lbs (10)

How to remove such attributes from layered navigation?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Basically, if all products from category have the same attribute value - the attribute filter doesn't make sense.

In the given example, all products have 2 lbs weight, therefore, no need for Weight filter to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

By default in Magento, the layered navigation shows all the attributes set to the products but we can hide the attribute from layered navigation using storefront properties for that attributes.
[image]